# Unable to fetch data from API (Resource blocked by client) in Vuex

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to fetch some data from my API using vuex + axios, but the action give me a "Network Error" (ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT).

when i was using json-server it works fine, but it doesn't work with my API even with **'Allow-Access-Control-Origin': '*'**

**actions**

```js
const actions = {
    async fetchSearch({ commit, state }) {
        let res
        try {
            res = await axios(`http://localhost:8000/api/advertisements/search?column=title&per_page=${state.params.per_page}&search_input=${state.params.query.toLowerCase()}&page=${state.params.page}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                mode: 'no-cors',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        commit('clearProducts')
        commit('setProducts', res.data)
    },

    setGlobalParams({ commit }, obj) {
        commit('clearParams')
        commit('setParams', obj)
    }
}
```

**component**

```js
<script>
/* Vuex import */
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'base-search-component',
    data() {
        return {
            query_obj: {
                page: 1,
                per_page: 8,
                query: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'fetchSearch',
            'setGlobalParams'
        ]),
        fetchData() {
            if (this.query_obj.query === '') {
                return
            } else {
                this.setGlobalParams(this.query_obj)
                this.fetchSearch()
                this.$router.push({ name: 'search', params: { query_obj: this.query_obj } })
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header, not a **request** header. Your API needs to send it.

Comment: @ceejayoz now my server is sending the header, but i cant fetch the data in the store action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your cors issue was properly resolved the reason you cannot access the data is that it is being set before the axios promise is being resolved.

Change:

```
async fetchSearch({ commit, state }) {
    let res
    try {
        res = await axios(`http://localhost:8000/api/advertisements/search?column=title&per_page=${state.params.per_page}&search_input=${state.params.query.toLowerCase()}&page=${state.params.page}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    commit('clearProducts')
    commit('setProducts', res.data)
}
```

to:

```
async fetchSearch({ commit, state }) {
    await axios(`http://localhost:8000/api/advertisements/search?column=title&per_page=${state.params.per_page}&search_input=${state.params.query.toLowerCase()}&page=${state.params.page}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        commit('clearProducts')
        commit('setProducts', response.data)
    }).catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Further you should use mapState. Assuming setProducts is setting a state object like products this would look like:

```
<script>
/* Vuex import */
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'base-search-component',
    data() {
        return {
            query_obj: {
                page: 1,
                per_page: 8,
                query: ''
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        mapState([
            'products'
        ])
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'fetchSearch',
            'setGlobalParams'
        ]),
        fetchData() {
            if (this.query_obj.query === '') {
                return
            } else {
                this.setGlobalParams(this.query_obj)
                this.fetchSearch()
                this.$router.push({ name: 'search', params: { query_obj: this.query_obj } })
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now you can refrence this.products in JS or products in your template.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the quick answers, the problem was a chrome tool that blocks the advertising the address of the API was **"localhost: 8000 / advertisement"**, after fixing the error of the headers on the server (thanks to @ceejayoz) my vuex store returned an empty object, but thanks to your answer I solved the problem